# Is full signature function overload ever necessary in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I got a little confused by the official TypeScript documentation, particularily the [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) page. There's this snippet in the docs:

```js
interface IdLabel {
  id: number /* some fields */;
}
interface NameLabel {
  name: string /* other fields */;
}
 
function createLabel(id: number): IdLabel;
function createLabel(name: string): NameLabel;
function createLabel(nameOrId: string | number): IdLabel | NameLabel; // Why?
function createLabel(nameOrId: string | number): IdLabel | NameLabel {
  throw "unimplemented";
}
```

I don't quite get it why would they include the third overload, which is identical to final function signature? Is it an overlook, or does it serve a purpose?

Comment: I observed that without the full overload, it won't show it in the documentation. For instance if you go to the playground, start typing `createLabel(` and then use the arrow down key to select the different signatures. This doesn't have functional effect though, only hints for developers

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature

Comment: *"the signature used to write the function body can’t be “seen” from the outside"*

Comment: Without the third overload, you wouldn't be able to call the function with a union as demonstrated [here](https://tsplay.dev/WPz45N) as the implementation signature is not visible to callers when an overload exists. Would this suffice as an answer?

Comment: @TobiasS. yeah I think so. I wish TypeScript handled these conditional types differently. I don't like it that it converts a ternary expression to a union type, as in reality it's only one of the types at a time. I hope I'm clear with what I want to say.

Comment: "_in reality it's only one of the types at a time_": from a runtime perspective, yes. The argument is either `string` or `number` when executing the function. But from a static analysis perspective, you can call it with arguments that you cannot tell in advance (i.e. without actually running the code) which type they are, hence they remain a union type. It is nicely illustrated by the code example in TobiasS.'s answer. Now if you are sure you will never call it like that, then you can omit that extra overload.

Answer (score 6):

TypeScript differentiates between two types of signatures whenever a function uses [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). The first type being *Overload Signatures* which describe all possible ways to call a function and the second one being the *Implementation Signature* which is used to write the body of the function.

The *Implementation Signature* is **not** considered as a valid call signature. It is only used to provide parameter typings for the implementation of the function.

- [Overload Signatures and the Implementation Signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature)

---

The third overload of your example is necessary to make the function callable with a `string | number` union.

```
function createLabel(id: number): IdLabel;
function createLabel(name: string): NameLabel;
function createLabel(nameOrId: string | number): IdLabel | NameLabel {
  throw "unimplemented";
}

createLabel(Math.random() > 0.5 ? "abc" : 123)
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Argument of type 'string | number' 
//                                            is not assignable to parameter 
//                                            of type 'string'
```

The compiler would prevent us from calling the function with a union; even if the argument type was compatible with the *implementation signature*.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBMAycBGEA2yA3gFDLLDoBcyIArgLZ5TID0AVMgM4D2DKMYAXRdk7VgG4SAXxKhIsRCgBycftjyFS5EGog0uYKKADmbTjzAALaMkHDR4qbOQkYdEAjDAeIZAigIOEgNAgAKShp6JmgAShoMUPwpd09vX39A4IgksN1+AyNTeORVdVwCFI8vHz8AoJCK-Dy9AHkoDELjEDMAH1pGZhLEpuR+spzR7WRrKB4Ad2QAIg9gBgAHfAh+cAh0JecSI-rs3IBZYKsAOig4EHQ+MNjkAD5kAAYrgFZkAH5l3AIJbIGgARgATABmWJAA)